# POST-запрос и js на странице

Tags: javascript, get

Хочу уточнить. Пусть у меня есть страница с `js` кодом например для гугл аналитики

```
<script>
    //....
    ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

если я из другой страницы в `php` отправлю `get` запрос с помощью `curl`, `js` на этой странице сработает? или обязательно нужно открывать страницу в браузере?

Comment: Нет. Необходим эмулятор браузерных движков: [Selenium](http://habrahabr.ru/post/152653/),  [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Для исполнения js надо или открывать в браузере или использовать спец. библиотеки, хотя не уверен что для php они есть.

Comment: А для чего есть?

Comment: Насколько я знаю есть для Java